# Serialize/deserialize a Dictionary with a comma-separated entry

Tags: json, asp.net-core, serialization, deserialization

I am developing a ASP.NET Core 3.1 website and I have data in a **Dictionary<string, object>** that I want to **Serialize/Deserialize** using **Microsoft System.Text.Json** (I am new to Json serialize/deserialize in fact). The data comes from a PostgreSQL DB query and one of the returned values is a comma-separated list of integers (converted to string) that results from the **STRING_AGG** function. The image below shows one of the entries of the Dictionary:

[image]

I serialize it using the following code. Please note that I have tried both Microsoft **System.Text.Json** and **Newtonsoft**.

```
jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
//jsonResult = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result);
```

The data in the **Dictionary** should be deserialized according to the following class structure:

[image]

I use the following code:

```
//IEnumerable<SeccGralContenidoViewModel> seccGralContenido = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<SeccGralContenidoViewModel>>(_seccGralContenidoRepository.Read());
IEnumerable<SeccGralContenidoViewModel> seccGralContenido = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <IEnumerable<SeccGralContenidoViewModel>>(_seccGralContenidoRepository.Read());
```

However, an exception is thrown when deserializing no matter if I use **Newtonsoft** or **System.Text.Json**:

[image]

I am originally using **System.Text.Json** namespace but I also tried using **Newtonsoft**. After analyzing a bit deeper, I see that the problem could be the way in which data is saved to the **Dictionary** but I have not found a workaround.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want `"       1,        2,       6"` to be deserialized as `string[] { "1", "2", "6" }` and vice versa.

Comment: You could try to assemble the string arrry as `{CategoriasContenidolds, {1,2,3}}`.

Comment: Yes, I want  "1,        2,       6" to be deserialized to string[] { "1", "2", "6" }

Comment: I had already tried getting the result as {[CategoriasContenidoIds, {"          1","          2","          6"}]} by using the PostgreSQL function STRING_TO_ARRAY but I still get the same error.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code and JSON as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  A compilable, runnable [mcve] would be awesome and maximize the chance someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my issue by directly getting JSON formatted results from queries. PostgreSQL does an excellent job. This way I also avoid performing a 2-step process: first, getting the query result; second, serializing to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write a custom converter then the simplest solution is to introduce another property:

```cs
public string CategoriasContenidolds {get; set;}

private static char delimiter = ',';
[JsonIgnore]
public string[] CategoriasContenidolds_Collection
{
    get => CategoriasContenidolds.Split(delimiter).Select(item => item.Trim()).ToArray();
    set => CategoriasContenidolds = string.Join(delimiter, value);
}
```

- The serializer will use the `CategoriasContenidolds` property during serialization and deserialization
- You should use `CategoriasContenidolds_Collection` (or name whatever you want) in your business logic

  - By explicitly marking this property with `JsonIgnore` the serializer will ignore that